# Protobuf in windows 8 app serialization or generating code not working

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-store-apps, protocol-buffers

I need use protobuf in my windows store app and I use this [Protobuf port](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/wiki/GettingStarted) but when I generate classes from proto file seen like not full because I dont have access to .newBuilder()... nad if I use p:lightFramework I still cannot work with .newBuilder()... Anyone can help?

Part of generated code without light framework options

```
[global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Person")]
```

Part of generated code with light framework options

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Person")]
```

Problem is there:(.newBuilder() is not recognized

```
CP.ConnectionResponse respp = CP.ConnectionResponse.newBuilder()...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using two different libraries at once; in particular, you seem to be following the *instructions* for [protobuf port](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/wiki/GettingStarted), but actually *using* [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted). These are two different libraries, connected only in so much as:

- they both target .NET
- they both serialize/deserialize protobuf data

To add context  - this is a bit like using JSON.NET but following the instructions for ServiceStack.Text: both can serialize/deserialize JSON, but the API is different.

You need to decide which library you *want* to use, and follow the instructions for that implementation.

As an aside: for the *best performance* on a store app / windows phone app with protobuf-net, you may also want to consider using the [precompiler](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html) - but you should be able to get it *working* (for a proof-of-concept etc) without this.

Comment: I need use protobuf-csharp-port but I already has to worry about the third day and I can not figure it out .( I download Version 2.4.1.521 release binaries only but I cannot generate classes from proto file. I use example and then I got this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40039421/a.PNG

Comment: @user2244495 the code in your question, with `ProtoBuf.ProtoContractAttribute` - that is protobuf-net code. Are you sure you are using the right "protogen" ? However, as for the screenshot - you must include the --proto_path *in the same command* as when you call `protogen`

Comment: thx for your answer now I can generate classes. I have one question maybe you had similar problem. When I use my generated class in W8 app I get this error https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40039421/e.png

Comment: @user2244495 well, I'm the protobuf-net guy; that is protobuf port - Jon Skeet is the person you want to ask. But: a `TypeInitializationException` means that a static constructor threw an exception; look at the `.InnerException` to see exactly what actually happened